# Felica (TYPE 3 NFC card) NDEF Message including the attribute block example ACR1252U

Tags: nfc, acr1252

I am hoping someone can help,

I am trying to write an NDEF URI message to a felica type card to store a link to a web resource. I am using a ACR1252U reader from advanced card systems.

Block 0 is for attribute data 
Block 1 onwards is user data where I would like to store the ndef record.

Does any one have an example of an encoded command to send to the card ie what should be written in block 0 and maybe a sample ndef message encoded to suit

ie 
Default:
Block 0 data: {10h, 01h, 01h, 00h, 09h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 01h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 1Ch} is meant to be for the attribute data but I am not sure this is correct for a NDEF record

i have then written to block 1
D1 01 13 55 01 69 74 64 69 73 63 6F 76 65 72 79 2E 63 6F 6D 2E 61 75

which should be a URI (WWW) type NDEF record with payload itdiscovery.com.au

when I try to scan the card with NFC tools (android) it detects the card type [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9I29M.jpg)

BUT no ndef message or record - I am not sure if i have to specify the service type and location etc. I am at a bit of a loss ANY INSIGHT APPRECIATED.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this flow[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CWrYt.png)

Comment: I am working on this now I will let you know how things pan out.

Answer (score 0):

T3T attribute block format:
[image: T3T Attribute Block Format]

In your case, the block 0 data should be:

> {10h, 04h, 01h, 00h, 09h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 00h, 01h, 00h, 00h, 17h, 00h, 36h}